# Use builtin and continuity camera at once on mac

Tags: macos, iphone, camera, webcam, continuity

I'd like to stream on twitch with the builtin camera on my macbook and add an external one with continuity cam (from my iphone 13 pro). Is this possible?

Also, can I use a different older iPhone 8 solely as a camera added, where I can just film my keyboard for example?

Comment: The probably best solution for a multi-cam setup is still OBS.

Comment: oh thanks i did not check it out yet!